# Write file in utf8 with nasm

Tags: assembly, io, nasm, i386

I was trying to get input from the user and write it to file
Using GHex i could see that the string stored correctly but file seems to be stored as binary file (Cannot be opened with gedit as text file)
How to fix that?

that is my code

```
section .data
CreateErrorPrompt:  db 'Error creating file',10
CreateErrorPromptSize:  equ $-CreateErrorPrompt
ArgCErrorPrompt:    db 'Please use $myeditor filename',10
ArgCErrorPromptSize:    equ $-ArgCErrorPrompt
inputBufferSize:    equ 84  ; the buffer size (in .bss section)

section .bss
inputBuffer:    resb 84 ; Buffer to read file in
filePointer:    resb 4  ; pointer for the file
fileDescriptor: resb 1  ; pointer for descriptor

section .text
global _start

_start:
nop

pop ebx     ; argc (argCount)
cmp ebx,2   ; make sure arguments are two
jne ArgCError   ; jump to ArgCError

pop ebx     ; name of the program
pop ebx     ; name of the file
cmp ebx,0   ; make sure entered falid file name
jbe ArgCError   ; print error if not valid
mov [filePointer],ebx   ; put file pointer

getInput:
mov eax,3   ; system call for read
mov ebx,0   ; read from stdin
mov ecx,inputBuffer ; read in input buffer
mov edx,inputBufferSize ; set input size
int 80h     ; call the kernel
jmp OpenTheFile

OpenTheFile:
mov eax,5   ; system call for open
mov ebx,[filePointer]   ; put file pointer
mov ecx,2   ; 0_RDWR
int 80h     ; call the kernel
cmp eax,0   ; check if opened succefully
jle CreateTheFile   ; Try to create
mov [fileDescriptor],eax    ; put file descriptor
jmp fileOpened

CreateTheFile:
mov eax,8   ; system call for creat
mov ebx,[filePointer]   ; put file pointer
mov ecx,0700    ; access rights -rwxr-xr-x
int 80h     ; call the kernel
cmp eax,0   ; check if file was created
jle errorCreating   ;error creating file
mov [fileDescriptor],eax    ; put file descriptor
jmp fileOpened

fileOpened:
writeToFile:
mov eax,4   ; system call for write
mov ebx,[fileDescriptor]    ; put file descriptor
mov ecx,inputBuffer ; write buffer
mov edx,inputBufferSize ; the size
int 80h     ; call the kernel
mov eax,36      ;sys_sync
int 80h
jmp CloseBeforeExit ; exit

errorCreating:
mov eax,4   ; system call for write
mov ebx,1   ; stdout
mov ecx,CreateErrorPrompt   ; offset to write
mov edx,CreateErrorPromptSize   ; length to be written
int 80h
jmp ExitProgram ; exit

ArgCError:
mov eax,4   ; system call for write
mov ebx,1   ; stdout
mov ecx,ArgCErrorPrompt ; offset to write
mov edx,ArgCErrorPromptSize ; length to be written
int 80h
jmp ExitProgram ; exit

CloseBeforeExit:
mov eax,6 ; system call for close
mov ebx,[fileDescriptor]    ; put file descriptor
int 80h     ; call the kernel
ExitProgram:
mov eax,1   ; The system call for exit (sys_exit)
mov ebx,0   ; Exit with return code of 0 (no error)
int 80h
```

Comment: Two problems: wrong file permissions if you create the file (`0700` is not octal in nasm) and you write too many bytes (you should check the return value from `read`)

Comment: What should be the file permissions? And I didn't understand the second problem.

Comment: [numeric constants in nasm](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.08/html/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.4.1) As for the second part: you always write out 84 bytes even if you didn't read that many from the user. That means you will have a bunch of binary zeroes in the file which is presumably what gedit chokes on.

Comment: @Jester convert your comment to answer and it is done